# Applescript Data from excel echo value then increment

Tags: applescript

all i'm trying to make an apple script that reads data from an excel spread sheet cell number B2, and sets var1 to the value of B2, but i want it to check the cell A2 that the time the system is at matches the value of A2 and if it does it takes the value of B2 and set it as the variable.

that would be the first time now the second time it will collect data from A3 & B3

```
   set SystemTime to (current date)

   set current_row to 2 #Set starting row
   repeat
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set a_cell to (get value of cell (("A" & current_row) as string)) #Get A cell val
    if a_cell = SystemTime then #If times match up
        set b_cell to (value of cell (("B" & current_row) as string)) #Get B         cell val
        display dialog b_cell #Display that val
        current_row = current_row + 1 #Increment the row we're looking at

    end if
  end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cell names need to be strings (in quotes), and they need to be casted into cell objects (ie `cell "A2"`). I'm not sure what you mean when you're asking that the second time the script collects data from `A3` and `B3`, when will it do that? In the else? And if not, what do you want to happen if `A2` **doesn't** match the system time? As of now I have it waiting two minutes and then trying again...Please be more clear as to what you're looking for.

```
repeat
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set a2 to (get value of cell "A2") 
        if a2 = SystemTime 
            set var to (Value of cell "B2")
            display dialog var
            exit repeat
        else
            delay 120 #wait 2 minutes
        end if
    end tell
end repeat
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, after your comment (assuming you want a waiting time of 2 minutes between checks):

```
set current_row to 2 #Set starting row
repeat
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set a_cell to (get value of cell (("A" & current_row) as string)) #Get A cell val
        if a_cell = SystemTime then #If times match up
            set b_cell to (value of cell (("B" & current_row) as string)) #Get B cell val
            display dialog var #Display that val
            current_row = current_row + 1 #Increment the row we're looking at
        else
            delay 120 #wait 2 minutes
        end if
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: lets say that i have a list of items in a2 and b2 a2 contains a time lets say "1800" and b2 contains a string lets say "test" so at they system time "1800" it will set the var to the value of b2 which would be "test", but the second time round it would collect data from a3, a3 will have the time 2000 and b3 will have the value "test2" so once its done a2 it will move onto a3 because a2 will have been used.

Comment: @MrJoshFisher Ahh, I understand. How often should the script be checking?

Comment: the script should check the file every 2 hours and is it possible to give the script a link to open the workbook to check rather then having microsoft excel open all the time whilst this script runs ?

Comment: see edit the time is too exact it shows seconds and it would confuse the script and miss the chance to go, it would need to be simplified to just 20:00 not 20:00:13 <-- seconds

Comment: You probably don't want the same script looping and running for hours on end. You can make an alarm and have it run the Applescript when it goes off every two hours, that should simplify things immensely.

Comment: @MrJoshFisher Furthermore, at the moment you're trying to compare a `string` to a `date object`, which probably isn't working out to well. Perhaps you could try comparing what you find in excel to `hours of (current date)` so that you won't have to check at exactly the right second for the script to work